# Newbie math checker for C. Why won't it work?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

printf("What is the sum of 5 + 5?\n");

GetInt();

if int == 10;

printf("Correct.\n");

}
```

Comment: Assuming this example is complete: `GetInt()` does not exist and the `if` statement isn't formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("What is the sum of 5 + 5?\n");
    GetInt();
    if(int == 10){
        printf("Correct.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`GetInt()` is undefined, you also have some very basic syntax errors(that I've corrected) for example `if int == 10;` `int` is a data type you can't compare it to a number and even if you could by putting a `;` at the end you basically putting and empty conditional, it won't do anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("What is the sum of 5 + 5?\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if(a == 10){
        printf("Correct.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what you want, now you should really read back the basics of C.

Comment: C is my first attempt at programming, just started 2 days ago. Thanks for your input, I was really just trying to get creative. Haven't even read about the scanf or % things yet lol. Going back to page 1 now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I never use ; with if statement but If I write this code I will write like this

```
int main(void)
{
   int res;

   printf("What is the sum of 5 + 5?\n");

   scanf("%d",&res)

   if (res == 10)
   {
       printf("Correct.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```